# Specify valid values for arguments using docopt

Tags: python, docopt

I am trying to use docopt for the first time.  So far, this is the usage statement I have:

```
Test Control Program

Usage: 
  test.py bitwrite ([--off=<bits>...][--on=<bits>...])
  test.py regwrite ([regA | regB]<value>)

Options:
  -o <bits>... --off <bits>...  #Turn bits off
  -i <bits>... --on <bits>...   #Turns bits on
```

So, not I have no problem with test.py bitwrite -o bitA, bitB, bitC, bitD

Let's say that there is a user unfamiliar with my system and they need to know the proper values for the bits values.

Is there any way to specify this using the usage statement?  I have tried several things and get nothing to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify them in a separate part of the `__doc__` , as an Example -

```
Test Control Program

Usage: 
  test.py bitwrite ([--off=<bits>...][--on=<bits>...])
  test.py regwrite ([regA | regB]<value>)

Options:
  -o <bits>... --off <bits>...  #Turn bits off
  -i <bits>... --on <bits>...   #Turns bits on

Arguments:

      bits: 1 - on
            0 - off
```

Please note `Arguments` is not any special name recognized by docopt , its just any name, you can use any such appropriate name you want.

In the above the `Arguments` section would show the valid values for bits, and other arguments .

Then when running the above doc with --help option, you would get result as -

```
>>>> python a.py --help
Test Control Program

Usage:
  test.py bitwrite ([--off=<bits>...][--on=<bits>...])
  test.py regwrite ([regA | regB]<value>)

Options:
  -o <bits>... --off <bits>...  #Turn bits off
  -i <bits>... --on <bits>...   #Turns bits on

Arguments:

      bits: 1 - on
            0 - off
```

---

If you want to show the complete `__doc__` without having to specify the `--help` or `-h` option, you can catch `DocoptExit` exception when calling the `docopt()` function and print the `__doc__` at that time.

Example -

```
"""Test Control Program

Usage: 
  test.py bitwrite ([--off=<bits>...][--on=<bits>...])
  test.py regwrite ([regA | regB]<value>)

Options:
  -o <bits>... --off <bits>...  #Turn bits off
  -i <bits>... --on <bits>...   #Turns bits on

Arguments:

      bits: 1 - on
            0 - off

"""
from docopt import docopt, DocoptExit


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        arguments = docopt(__doc__, version='Test Control Program')
        print(arguments)
    except DocoptExit:
        print(__doc__)
```