# Docopt required flag where the value for it can only be one of a few options

Tags: bash, arguments, command-line-arguments, docopt

I am using the shell implementation of docopt, called [`docopts`](https://github.com/docopt/docopts), to write a script. I want the script to have a flag argument, `--myflag`, where the value can only be one of a few valid choices: `foo`, `bar`, or `baz`. So, I tried this:

```
eval "$(docopts -h - : "$@" <<DOCOPTS
My program: do some stuff

Usage:
  myprogram --myflag foo
  myprogram --myflag bar
  myprogram --myflag baz

Options:
  -m --myflag=MYVALUE    This should only be foo, bar, or baz. 
DOCOPTS
)"

echo the value of myflag is: $myflag
```

But I do not get an error when I try running the program with a different value for `--myflag`:

```
$ myprogram --myflag dog
the value of myflag is: dog
```

I was expecting to see the usage message instead. Obviously, I could do the validation myself, but I was hoping docopt could handle that. What am I doing wrong?

*Note: my use case seems different enough (different programming language, different argument structure) from [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31601488/specify-valid-values-for-arguments-using-docopt), so I don't think this is a duplicate.*

Comment: I'm not familiar with docopt or docopts, but I can see that the code posted will generate errors if pasted into the shell linting service at https://shellcheck.net . You'll need to include the appropriate `#!/bin/bash` as the first line. Good luck.

Comment: Also, try to make a simpler test case to prove to yourself that `docopts` is working the way you need it to work. Add in the `eval`, `$(...cmd <<DOCOPTS` , etc stuff only after you have seen the cmd work correctly. AND add those extra features in one at a time to see where things are breaking. Good luck.

Comment: And, I see that is a closing paren, not a curly brace, (as I originally thought), so you may not get any errors from shellcheck ;-)! .

Comment: @shellter for the sake of making the question not too long, I didn't include the shebang. Also this is already a simpler test case! You do not want to see the real code, this proof of concept is sufficient for considering the problem. :)